# Sum of squares of determinants of principal minors

Tags: determinants, sums-of-squares

I am interested in computing the sum of squares of determinants of principal minors.  Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ positive semidefinite matrix and $A_S$ be a principal minor of $A$ indexed by the set $S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$.  The classical result (without squares) is:

$\sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}} \det(A_S) = \det(A+I)$

Are there any results on computing

$\sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}} \det^2(A_S)$

or any other powers?

Comment: Do you have a reference for the classical result? It does not ring a bell somehow...

Comment: Horn & Johnson has some background:

http://books.google.com/books?id=PlYQN0ypTwEC&lpg=PA42&vq=sum%20of%20principal%20minors&dq=sum%20of%20all%20principal%20minors&pg=PA40#v=snippet&q=sum%20of%20principal%20minors&f=false

Comment: @Thierry. Imagine that you compute instead $\det(A+XI)$. Then expand in the indeterminate $X$.

Comment: @Ben. I don't think that positive semidefiniteness plays a role here.

Comment: I agree, it's not necessary for the classical result.  My particular problem has the additional psd constraint, which may or may not make the extension easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The identity you mention does generalize to sums of powers, but I don't know if it can give you anything computationally efficient. Given a set $X\subset \mathbb R$, let $D(X^n)$ denote all $n\times n$ diagonal matrices with diagonal elements from $X$. Then if you take $X_k=\{1,\omega,\cdots,\omega^{k-1}\}$ the $k$-th roots of unity, the following holds
$$\sum_{S\subset \{1,2,\cdots,n\}}\det(A_S)^k=\frac{1}{k^n}\sum_{M\in D(X^n)}\det(A+M)^k$$
the proof is basically the same as the one for the case $k=1$ with a few more algebraic manipulations.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting!  Not sure how to make it computationally efficient.

Comment: BTW, do you have a reference for this result?